EF Core 8 - Load many-to-many relationship results in NullReferenceException
I have an ASP.NET Core web application with a SQL Server database using EF Core 6. This works fine. Today I've tried to upgrade the application to .NET 8 but I'm experiencing problems in EF Core.
I've uploaded a demo application here. I've migrated some code step-by-step. But from the moment I implement the many-to-many relationship of Subject and Tag I start getting a NullReferenceException from the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore assembly:
public class DemoContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public DemoContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        var connectionstring = configuration.GetConnectionString("Application");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionstring);
        //optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("Application");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Subjects
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().ToTable("Subjects");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().HasQueryFilter(s => s.UserDelete == null);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().HasDiscriminator<string>("SubjectType")
            .HasValue<Song>("song");

        // Tag category
        modelBuilder.Entity<TagCategory>().Property(tc => tc.Color).HasConversion(color => color.ToArgb(), argb => System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(argb));

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
        //    .HasMany(s => s.Tags)
        //    .WithMany(t => new List<Subject>())
        //    .UsingEntity<SubjectTag>();

        // Many-to-many Subject-Tag
        //modelBuilder.Entity<SubjectTag>().HasKey(st => new { st.SubjectId, st.TagId });
        //modelBuilder.Entity<SubjectTag>().HasOne(st => st.Subject).WithMany(s => s.Tags).HasForeignKey(st => st.SubjectId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<SubjectTag>().HasOne(st => st.Tag).WithMany(t => t.Subjects).HasForeignKey(st => st.TagId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Tags)
            .WithMany(t => t.Subjects)
            .UsingEntity<SubjectTag>();
    }

    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Medium> Media { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MediumType> MediumTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TagCategory> TagCategories { get; set; }
}

Retrieving a song from the database:
var song = await context.Songs
    .Include(s => s.Media)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.Type)
    // Comment out includes below to make it work
    .Include(s => s.Tags)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Category)
    //.AsNoTracking()
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == 23);



The working .NET 6 application is hosted here.
Does anyone know what's changed in .NET 8 that causes the database not to be forward compatible from .NET 6?
EDIT
Old SQL Query (.NET 6)
var query = mintplayer_context.Songs
    .Include(s => s.Lyrics)
    .Include(s => s.Artists)
        .ThenInclude(@as => @as.Artist)
    .Include(s => s.Media)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.Type)
    .Include(s => s.Tags)
        .ThenInclude(st => st.Tag)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.Category)
    .ToQueryString();

SQL
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[ConcurrencyStamp], [s].[DateDelete], [s].[DateInsert], [s].[DateUpdate], [s].[SubjectType], [s].[UserDeleteId], [s].[UserInsertId], [s].[UserUpdateId], [s].[Released], [s].[Title], [a].[Id], [l].[SongId], [l].[UserId], [l].[Text], [l].[Timeline], [l].[UpdatedAt], [t0].[ArtistId], [t0].[SongId], [t0].[Credited], [t0].[Id], [t0].[ConcurrencyStamp], [t0].[DateDelete], [t0].[DateInsert], [t0].[DateUpdate], [t0].[SubjectType], [t0].[UserDeleteId], [t0].[UserInsertId], [t0].[UserUpdateId], [t0].[Name], [t0].[YearQuit], [t0].[YearStarted], [t0].[Id0], [t1].[Id], [t1].[SubjectId], [t1].[TypeId], [t1].[Value], [t1].[Id0], [t1].[Description], [t1].[UserDeleteId], [t1].[UserInsertId], [t1].[UserUpdateId], [t1].[Visible], [t1].[Id00], [t3].[SubjectId], [t3].[TagId], [t3].[Id], [t3].[CategoryId], [t3].[DateDelete], [t3].[DateInsert], [t3].[DateUpdate], [t3].[Description], [t3].[ParentId], [t3].[UserDeleteId], [t3].[UserInsertId], [t3].[UserUpdateId], [t3].[Id0], [t3].[Color], [t3].[DateDelete0], [t3].[DateInsert0], [t3].[DateUpdate0], [t3].[Description0], [t3].[UserDeleteId0], [t3].[UserInsertId0], [t3].[UserUpdateId0], [t3].[Id00], [t3].[Id01]
FROM [Subjects] AS [s]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [s].[UserDeleteId] = [a].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Lyrics] AS [l] ON [s].[Id] = [l].[SongId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [a0].[ArtistId], [a0].[SongId], [a0].[Credited], [t].[Id], [t].[ConcurrencyStamp], [t].[DateDelete], [t].[DateInsert], [t].[DateUpdate], [t].[SubjectType], [t].[UserDeleteId], [t].[UserInsertId], [t].[UserUpdateId], [t].[Name], [t].[YearQuit], [t].[YearStarted], [t].[Id0]
    FROM [ArtistSong] AS [a0]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [s0].[Id], [s0].[ConcurrencyStamp], [s0].[DateDelete], [s0].[DateInsert], [s0].[DateUpdate], [s0].[SubjectType], [s0].[UserDeleteId], [s0].[UserInsertId], [s0].[UserUpdateId], [s0].[Name], [s0].[YearQuit], [s0].[YearStarted], [a1].[Id] AS [Id0]
        FROM [Subjects] AS [s0]
        LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a1] ON [s0].[UserDeleteId] = [a1].[Id]
        WHERE ([s0].[SubjectType] = N'artist') AND [a1].[Id] IS NULL
    ) AS [t] ON [a0].[ArtistId] = [t].[Id]
) AS [t0] ON [s].[Id] = [t0].[SongId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[SubjectId], [m].[TypeId], [m].[Value], [t2].[Id] AS [Id0], [t2].[Description], [t2].[UserDeleteId], [t2].[UserInsertId], [t2].[UserUpdateId], [t2].[Visible], [t2].[Id0] AS [Id00]
    FROM [Media] AS [m]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [m0].[Id], [m0].[Description], [m0].[UserDeleteId], [m0].[UserInsertId], [m0].[UserUpdateId], [m0].[Visible], [a2].[Id] AS [Id0]
        FROM [MediumTypes] AS [m0]
        LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a2] ON [m0].[UserDeleteId] = [a2].[Id]
        WHERE [a2].[Id] IS NULL
    ) AS [t2] ON [m].[TypeId] = [t2].[Id]
) AS [t1] ON [s].[Id] = [t1].[SubjectId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [s1].[SubjectId], [s1].[TagId], [t4].[Id], [t4].[CategoryId], [t4].[DateDelete], [t4].[DateInsert], [t4].[DateUpdate], [t4].[Description], [t4].[ParentId], [t4].[UserDeleteId], [t4].[UserInsertId], [t4].[UserUpdateId], [t5].[Id] AS [Id0], [t5].[Color], [t5].[DateDelete] AS [DateDelete0], [t5].[DateInsert] AS [DateInsert0], [t5].[DateUpdate] AS [DateUpdate0], [t5].[Description] AS [Description0], [t5].[UserDeleteId] AS [UserDeleteId0], [t5].[UserInsertId] AS [UserInsertId0], [t5].[UserUpdateId] AS [UserUpdateId0], [t4].[Id0] AS [Id00], [t5].[Id0] AS [Id01]
    FROM [SubjectTag] AS [s1]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [t6].[Id], [t6].[CategoryId], [t6].[DateDelete], [t6].[DateInsert], [t6].[DateUpdate], [t6].[Description], [t6].[ParentId], [t6].[UserDeleteId], [t6].[UserInsertId], [t6].[UserUpdateId], [a3].[Id] AS [Id0]
        FROM [Tags] AS [t6]
        LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a3] ON [t6].[UserDeleteId] = [a3].[Id]
        WHERE [a3].[Id] IS NULL
    ) AS [t4] ON [s1].[TagId] = [t4].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [t7].[Id], [t7].[Color], [t7].[DateDelete], [t7].[DateInsert], [t7].[DateUpdate], [t7].[Description], [t7].[UserDeleteId], [t7].[UserInsertId], [t7].[UserUpdateId], [a4].[Id] AS [Id0]
        FROM [TagCategories] AS [t7]
        LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a4] ON [t7].[UserDeleteId] = [a4].[Id]
        WHERE [a4].[Id] IS NULL
    ) AS [t5] ON [t4].[CategoryId] = [t5].[Id]
) AS [t3] ON [s].[Id] = [t3].[SubjectId]
WHERE ([s].[SubjectType] = N'song') AND [a].[Id] IS NULL
ORDER BY [s].[Id], [a].[Id], [l].[SongId], [l].[UserId], [t0].[ArtistId], [t0].[SongId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Id0], [t1].[Id], [t1].[Id0], [t1].[Id00], [t3].[SubjectId], [t3].[TagId], [t3].[Id], [t3].[Id00], [t3].[Id0]

New SQL Query (.NET 8)
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[DateDelete], [s].[DateInsert], [s].[DateUpdate], [s].[SubjectType], [s].[UserDeleteId], [s].[UserInsertId], [s].[UserUpdateId], [s].[Title], [a].[Id], [t].[Id], [t].[SubjectId], [t].[TypeId], [t].[Value], [t].[Id0], [t].[Description], [t1].[SubjectId], [t1].[TagId], [t1].[Id], [t1].[CategoryId], [t1].[DateDelete], [t1].[DateInsert], [t1].[DateUpdate], [t1].[Description], [t1].[ParentId], [t1].[UserDeleteId], [t1].[UserInsertId], [t1].[UserUpdateId], [t1].[Id0], [t1].[Color], [t1].[Description0]
FROM [Subjects] AS [s]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [s].[UserDeleteId] = [a].[Id]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[SubjectId], [m].[TypeId], [m].[Value], [m0].[Id] AS [Id0], [m0].[Description]
    FROM [Media] AS [m]
    INNER JOIN [MediumTypes] AS [m0] ON [m].[TypeId] = [m0].[Id]
) AS [t] ON [s].[Id] = [t].[SubjectId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [s0].[SubjectId], [s0].[TagId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[CategoryId], [t0].[DateDelete], [t0].[DateInsert], [t0].[DateUpdate], [t0].[Description], [t0].[ParentId], [t0].[UserDeleteId], [t0].[UserInsertId], [t0].[UserUpdateId], [t2].[Id] AS [Id0], [t2].[Color], [t2].[Description] AS [Description0]
    FROM [SubjectTag] AS [s0]
    INNER JOIN [Tags] AS [t0] ON [s0].[TagId] = [t0].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [TagCategories] AS [t2] ON [t0].[CategoryId] = [t2].[Id]
) AS [t1] ON [s].[Id] = [t1].[SubjectId]
WHERE [a].[Id] IS NULL
ORDER BY [s].[Id], [a].[Id], [t].[Id], [t].[Id0], [t1].[SubjectId], [t1].[TagId], [t1].[Id]


Can you enabled "see the generated sql" and see if there is a difference?
            //optionsBuilder is a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder
            //// Probably should not log sql statements in production !!! 
            optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(this.loggerFactory);
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors();


@granadaCoder Thanks, I added the SQL queries using ToQueryString()

Yeah.  That is "different".  While I don't know what the fix is, at least this points to why it is different/breaking in net8.0.

Hi @Pieterjan, I download your application code, and I’m unable to replicate the error you encountered. So I want to confirm a few things with you. Did the NullReferenceException error occur while executing the query? And are the two SQL queries you posted there generated from the same query statement? Because the query statement includes other tables, such as Lyrics and Artists. You can check it first.
